# TypeError: _fire__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.default.auth is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, jsx

I am a beginner at React.js. I was following a tutorial to make a login authentication. I am getting this error (TypeError: *fire__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1*_.default.auth is not a function) from this part of the code:
`

```
const authListener = () => {
    fire.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        clearInputs();
        setUser(user);
      } else {
        setUser("");
      }
    })
  };
```

`
I've already searched every forum, topic, or Youtube video and still can't find the answer. Can someone tell me where the problem is and how to fix it? Appreciate everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Modular SDK `v9.0.0` then try refactoring your code like this:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app"
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth"

const app = initializeApp(app)
const auth = getAuth(app)

const authListener = () => {
  onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    if (user) {
      console.log(user)
    }
  })
}
```

If you want to use the older namespaced syntax (`firebase.auth()`) then change your imports to compat version:

```
import firebase from "firebase/comapt/app"
import "firebase/compat/auth"
```

You can read more about upgrading to modular SDK in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#get_the_version_9_sdk).

Comment: I didn't know about the compat and modular versions. After some research, I found this documentation firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade and changed the imports and the function itself. And now it's working. For everyone who is reading this and has the same problem as me, I suggest visiting the site I provided a link to. Hope it helps. By the way, many thanks for the help